# OpenGL & HTML Canvas

Tags: jquery, python, cakephp, opengl, canvas

How can I use OpenGL for canvas programming?Recently I am working on canvas programming.Previous I used OpenGL in Java/C++/Python. But now want to use it with JavaScript or such kind library e.g. jQuery. But how? Pls help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into WebGL. I don't think it's a w3c standard yet, but the way things are going it'll probably become one.

http://www.khronos.org/webgl/